# When does python stop on a line in tracing with more than one stopping point on a line?

Tags: python, bytecode, pdb, trace

Consider these two examples:

```
x = 1; y = 2; z = 3
```

and:

```
for i in range(3): print(i)
```

In the latter, if you step through this in a debugger like *pdb*, you'll it will stop at the `print(i)` at each iteration of a loop.

However in the first example, it stops once.

Investigating further, disassembling the multi-statement line we see that there are in fact two entries for the first line in `co_lnotab`. But `dis.dis()` lies about this.

As for the *for* loop there is just the one line in the `lnotab` but the place that you stop at on each interation, offset 10, is at the target of a jump. So is that what triggers stopping even though the line number hasn't changed?

```
import dis
>>> x = compile('x = 1; y = 2; z = 3', 'foo', 'exec')
>>> x.co_lnotab
b'\x04\x00\x04\x00'
>>> dis.dis(x)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (y)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             10 STORE_NAME               2 (z)
             12 LOAD_CONST               3 (4)
             14 STORE_NAME               3 (a)
             16 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
>>> y = compile('for i in range(3): print(i)', 'foo', 'exec')
>>> y.co_lnotab
b'\x0e\x00'
>>> dis.dis(y)
  1           0 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 26)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (3)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                12 (to 24)
             12 STORE_NAME               1 (i)
             14 LOAD_NAME                2 (print)
             16 LOAD_NAME                1 (i)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             20 POP_TOP
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   24 POP_BLOCK
        >>   26 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Where is the source code for this logic? I've looked in the Python C code, but I can't find it, say in `ceval.c` looking for `PyTrace_LINE`.

*Edit*:

Based on user2357112's answer and reading the code suggested there, I was able to verify that one *can* stop/trace on each statement of the code.
I used my new Python assembler, [pyc-xasm](https://github.com/rocky/python-xasm), to modify the bytecode to this:

```
  2:
            LOAD_CONST           (1)
            STORE_NAME           (x)
            JUMP_FORWARD         L2B

L2A:
  2:
            LOAD_CONST           (2)
            STORE_NAME           (y)
            JUMP_FORWARD         L2D
L2B:
            JUMP_ABSOLUTE        L2A

L2C:
  2:
            LOAD_CONST           (3)
            STORE_NAME           (z)
            JUMP_FORWARD         L3
L2D:
            JUMP_ABSOLUTE        L2C

L3:
  3:
            LOAD_NAME            (x)
            LOAD_NAME            (y)
            BINARY_ADD
            LOAD_NAME            (z)
            BINARY_ADD
            PRINT_ITEM
            PRINT_NEWLINE
            LOAD_CONST           (None)
            RETURN_VALUE
```

And running this will cause Python to stop before each line.

Comment: I'm very curious about what's led you to look into this. What are you working on?

Comment: For a very long time, I have been working on debuggers, which includes python debuggers. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan3k.

I think you should be able to set a breakpoint where ever you want, which could be done by specifying a bytecode offset in a function. Or decide which statement of the multiple statements to stop at. With the advance of some recent bytecode manipulation tools, I am within reach of doing that. It's a lot of work though, and might not cover every case.

Comment: Awesome! I'm working on a python debugger right now (literally) that you may be interested in: https://github.com/alexmojaki/birdseye

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDB tracing uses a trace function set through [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace). There are a number of events that will trigger the trace function, but the ones you're looking at are all *line* events:

> `'line'`
>   The interpreter is about to **execute a new line of code** or **re-execute the condition of a loop**. The local trace function is called; *arg* is `None`; the return value specifies the new local trace function. See `Objects/lnotab_notes.txt` for a detailed explanation of how this works.

As the docs say, you can see a more detailed explanation of the line event triggers in [`Objects/lnotab_notes.txt`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/lnotab_notes.txt). The most relevant section is

> We fix this by only calling the line trace function for a forward jump if the
>   co_lnotab indicates we have jumped to the *start* of a line, i.e. if the current
>   instruction offset matches the offset given for the start of a line by the
>   co_lnotab.  For backward jumps, however, we always call the line trace function,
>   which lets a debugger stop on every evaluation of a loop guard (which usually
>   won't be the first opcode in a line).

So PDB will pause on the start of a line, or if execution jumps backward in the code.

---

If you want to see the source code that triggers line events, it's in `Python/ceval.c` under [`maybe_call_line_trace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/ceval.c#L4530). PDB's source code is, predictably, under [`Lib/pdb.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/pdb.py).